# Error when enter down the line in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use TyniMCE for my react-app. I config MCE init like this:

```js
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';
.... 
 <Editor
          init={
            selector: 'textarea',
            height: 500,
            menubar: false,
            plugins: [
              'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
              'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
              'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
            ],
            toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help'
          }
          disabled={disabled}
          name={name}
          value={value}
          onChange={this.handleEditorChange}
        />
```

and here is my display:

[image]

but when I press the enter Button to enter new line. But it adds 1 line above but not below. like this

[image]

I want to 1 > 2 > 3 > 4 > 5. But result is 5 > 4 > 3 > 2 > 1.

Please help me, how to fix it?

Sorry for my weak English skill

Answer (score 1):

You are using Controlled Component so you need to replace the onChange props with onEditorChange and it will resolve the issue.
**NOTE**
You will get value in onEditorChange instead of the event object.
here's an example,

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';

const Tinymce = ({
    value,
    onChange,
    height = 350,
    id = 'tinymce',
    menubar = false,
}) => {

const handleEditorChange = (value) => {
    onChange && onChange(value)
}

return (
    <Editor
        id={id}
        value={value}
        init={{
            height,
            menubar,
            plugins: [
                'advtable advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
                'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen visualchars',
                'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount directionality emoticons'
            ],
            toolbar:
                'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor link | \
         alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
         bullist numlist | outdent indent| table media code anchor emoticons directionality visualchars | preview | removeformat | help'
        }}
        onEditorChange={handleEditorChange}
        />
    );
}

export default Tinymce;
```